# Java: Why isn't this method recognized?

Tags: java

I am having a problem where a method from another class is not being recognized as existing by Eclipse, even though all the other methods are. I have no idea why this is happening, and cannot figure it out. I get the error `The method getData() is undefined for the type TMXReader.TMXHandler` when I try doing this:

```
package tiled.simple.reader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import tiled.simple.core.Map;
import tiled.simple.core.MapLayer;
import tiled.simple.core.TileSet;
import davidiserovich.TMXLoader.TMXHandler;
import davidiserovich.TMXLoader.TileMapData;



TMXHandler handler = new TMXHandler();

handler.getData();
```

Here is the TMXHandler class:

```
package davidiserovich.TMXLoader;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

//import android.sax.StartElementListener;

public class TMXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    /*
     * This is an SAX2 XML parser that interprets the input TMX file and creates
     * a TileMapData object.
     */

    // NOTE: Map Object loading is not yet implemented

    // Markers for which tag we're in
    private boolean inTileSet, inTile, inLayer, inData, inObjectGroup,
            inProperties;

    // ID of the current tile that we're adding properties to.
    // This is actually an OFFSET from firstGID of the tile in
    // the tileset. Beware.
    private String currentTileID;
    private String currentObjectGroupName;
    TileMapData.TMXObject currentObject;

    TileMapData.TileSet currentTileSet;
    TileMapData.Layer currentLayer;

    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> currentTileSetProperties;
    HashMap<String, String> currentLayerProperties;

    private TileMapData data;

    /*
     * These fields hold the buffer and data to help decode the long stream of
     * gids in the data field
     */
    private char buffer[];
    private int bufferIndex;
    private int currentX;
    private int currentY;
    public int MAX_INT_DECIMAL_LENGTH = 10;

    public TMXHandler() {
        super();
        buffer = new char[MAX_INT_DECIMAL_LENGTH];
        bufferIndex = 0;
        currentX = 0;
        currentY = 0;
    }

    public TileMapData getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        data = new TileMapData();
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {

    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
            String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("map")) {
            // inMap = true;
            // Check that the orientation is orthogonal
            if (!(atts.getValue("orientation").equals("orthogonal"))) {
                throw new SAXException(
                        "Unsupported orientation. Parse Terminated.");
            }
            data.orientation = atts.getValue("orientation");
            data.height = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("height"));
            data.width = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("width"));
            data.tilewidth = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("tilewidth"));
            data.tileheight = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("tileheight"));

            // data.sectionId = atts.getValue("id");
        } else if (localName.equals("tileset")) {
            inTileSet = true;
            currentTileSet = new TileMapData.TileSet();
            currentTileSet.firstGID = Integer.parseInt(atts
                    .getValue("firstgid"));
            currentTileSet.tileWidth = Integer.parseInt(atts
                    .getValue("tilewidth"));
            currentTileSet.tileHeight = Integer.parseInt(atts
                    .getValue("tileheight"));
            currentTileSet.name = atts.getValue("name");
            currentTileSetProperties = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

        } else if (inTileSet && localName.equals("image")) {
            currentTileSet.ImageFilename = atts.getValue("source");
            currentTileSet.imageWidth = Integer
                    .parseInt(atts.getValue("width"));
            currentTileSet.imageHeight = Integer.parseInt(atts
                    .getValue("height"));

        } else if (inTileSet && localName.equals("tile")) {
            inTile = true;
            currentTileID = atts.getValue("id");

        } else if (inTile && localName.equals("properties")) {
            inProperties = true;
            currentTileSetProperties.put(currentTileID,
                    new HashMap<String, String>());

        } else if (inLayer && localName.equals("properties")) {
            inProperties = true;

        } else if (inTile && inProperties && localName.equals("property")) {
            (currentTileSetProperties.get(currentTileID)).put(
                    atts.getValue("name"), atts.getValue("value"));

        } else if (inLayer && inProperties && localName.equals("property")) {
            currentLayerProperties.put(atts.getValue("name"),
                    atts.getValue("value"));
        } else if (localName.equals("layer")) {
            inLayer = true;

            currentLayer = new TileMapData.Layer();
            currentLayer.name = atts.getValue("name");
            currentLayer.width = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("width"));
            currentLayer.height = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("height"));
            if (atts.getValue("opacity") != null)
                currentLayer.opacity = Double.parseDouble(atts
                        .getValue("opacity"));
            currentLayer.tiles = new long[currentLayer.height][currentLayer.width];

            currentLayerProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();

        } else if (localName.equals("data")) {
            /*
             * Data is loaded directly into the int array in characters() We
             * just check if the encoding is supported here.
             */
            inData = true;
            String encoding = atts.getValue("encoding");
            if (!encoding.equals("csv")) {
                throw new SAXException(
                        "Unsupported encoding. Parse Terminated.");
            }

        } else if (localName.equals("objectgroup")) {
            inObjectGroup = true;
            currentObjectGroupName = atts.getValue("name");

        } else if (localName.equals("object")) {
            currentObject = new TileMapData.TMXObject();
            currentObject.name = atts.getValue("name");
            currentObject.type = atts.getValue("type");
            currentObject.x = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("x"));
            currentObject.y = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("y"));
            currentObject.width = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("width"));
            currentObject.height = Integer.parseInt(atts.getValue("height"));
            if (inObjectGroup) {
                currentObject.objectGroup = currentObjectGroupName;
            } else {
                currentObject.objectGroup = null;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equals("map")) {
            // inMap = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("tileset")) {
            inTileSet = false;
            currentTileSet.properties = currentTileSetProperties;
            currentTileSetProperties = null;
            data.tilesets.add(currentTileSet);
            currentTileSet = null; // Clear it just in case

        } else if (localName.equals("tile")) {
            inTile = false;
            currentTileID = "-1"; // -1 won't be produced when searching for
                                    // properties. Just a safeguard for
                                    // improperly formatted files.

        } else if (localName.equals("properties")) {
            inProperties = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("layer")) {
            inLayer = false;
            currentLayer.properties = currentLayerProperties;
            data.layers.add(currentLayer);
            currentLayer = null; // Clear it just in case
        } else if (localName.equals("data")) {
            inData = false;
            // In case we missed the last entry (no non-numeral chars before tag
            // end)
            if (bufferIndex > 0) {
                currentLayer.tiles[currentY][currentX] = Long
                        .parseLong(new String(buffer, 0, bufferIndex));
            }
            // Clear buffer
            bufferIndex = 0;
            currentX = 0;
            currentY = 0;

        } else if (localName.equals("objectgroup")) {
            inObjectGroup = false;

        } else if (localName.equals("object")) {
            data.objects.add(currentObject);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        /*
         * Java has no unsigned types, so we have to use a long instead of an
         * int so we can "simulate" an unsigned int. Disgusting. Anyway, we're
         * going to add the numbers from the character stream to a buffer until
         * we hit a comma, at which point we empty the buffer and convert it to
         * a long, and dump it into the array. These are raw, so the horizontal
         * and vertical flip bits may be set - to get the actual GID number,
         * we'll use TileMapData's getGIDAt(x, y), which will mask it properly.
         */
        if (inData) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (ch[start + i] <= '9' && ch[start + i] >= '0') {
                    buffer[bufferIndex] = ch[start + i];
                    // Log.d("Wrote to index", String.valueOf(bufferIndex));
                    bufferIndex++;

                } else {
                    // When we hit a comma or any non-number character, empty
                    // the buffer and enter the relevant
                    // GID into the data field
                    // int what = Integer.parseInt(new String(buffer, 0,
                    // bufferIndex));
                    // Log.d("Number", new String(buffer, 0, bufferIndex));
                    String nextNumber = new String(buffer, 0, bufferIndex);
                    if ((nextNumber != null) && ((nextNumber.trim()) != "")
                            && (bufferIndex != 0)) {
                        // Log.d("Checking", nextNumber + " yes");
                        currentLayer.tiles[currentY][currentX] = Long
                                .parseLong(nextNumber);
                        bufferIndex = 0;

                        // Move to the next tile
                        if (currentX < (currentLayer.width - 1)) {
                            currentX++;

                        } else if (currentY < (currentLayer.height - 1)) {
                            currentX = 0;
                            currentY++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Auto-complete shows all the other methods as usable, but for some reason getData "doesn't exist"...

I'm sure this is apparent for experienced Java programmers, but I have no idea why this is happening... so if anyone could tell me why, I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: You should use package names in small case. Your import `import davidiserovich.TMXLoader.TMXHandler;` looks like you are importing inner class.

Comment: You're showing TMXLoader.TMXHandler but your error says TMXReader.TMXHandler. Are you sure your imports are correct?

Comment: Other imports work fine. I don't know why it shows up as TMXReader.TMXHandler.

Comment: Double check the imports, see that you're not importing the Reader version in your java file as well as the loader version. Make sure your init line for your variable isn't using the fully qualified name format to declare variables...

Comment: I checked, and it's not. There is no TMXHandler file in that project. I updated my question with all my imports just in case I'm missing it...

Comment: Are this 2 files resides in 2 different projects?

Comment: @HarryJoy Yes, they are in different projects.

Comment: then you should check if you are referring to correct project in class/build path. May be you are referring to wrong project, just a guess !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
TMXHandler handler = new TMXHandler;
```

To this:

```
 TMXHandler handler = new TMXHandler();
```

**EDIT**

If it's just a typo issue... and if your question is complete... You may have forgot to put it in a class ? :<

```
import davidiserovich.TMXLoader.TMXHandler;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TMXHandler handler = new TMXHandler();
        handler.getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just a typo... it has the parentheses in the Java file, I just typed something up quickly and forgot to type them here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create object. You have forget ()

```
 TMXHandler handler = new TMXHandler();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the java code which is referring `TMXHandler` class have correct `TMXHandler.class` file in Runtime. This may be caused by old `TMXHandler.class` which dont have `getData()` method defined.

maybe try a clean build

Comment: I've tried cleaning both this project and the TMXLoader project, and nothing.

Comment: If you are using Maven then try deleting that artifact from Repo. It might be using TMXHandler from Repo jar.

Comment: you are using wrong jar in Runtime thats for sure. I guess you can check project class-path to see which jar you are using.

Comment: No, I'm using the right one. I checked the TMXHandler.class with JD-GUI, and getData is in there.

Comment: Really long solution. I dont know does this even make sense. try to list all method names using reflection and see if getData is there. Worth trying :)

Answer (score 0):

`TMXHandler handler = new TMXHandler;`

**The above line is the culprit.**

**-** When we call new on a `Class name` its always accompanied by `()` as **postfix**, which indicates the constructor of the class whose object is now created on the heap.

**-** And this line gives the opportunity to step in, to initialize the state of the object before the `Actual object` is assigned to the `Object reference variable`.

**So it should be....**

`TMXHandler handler = new TMXHandler();`

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in a comment, this is simply a typo. In the .java file the parentheses are there, and I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it... turns out that the one project already had a class named TMXHandler, so it was referring to that, and not my other project... A very stupid mistake. :